# flutter type mismatch from the the same file

Tags: flutter

I am getting a mysterious error from flutter.

type 'Receipt' is not a subtype of type 'Receipt' of 'receipt' where

> Receipt is from
>   file://Users/arash/source/shoppers/lib/services/receipt.dart
>
> Receipt is from
>
> package:shoppers/services/receipt.dart

The thing is, both of those files are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `package:...` imports instead of relative imports everywhere.

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9319

This is a Flutter specific issue because otherwise Dart canonicalizes relative and absolute imports and recognizes them as the same.